# Magento - Minimum order quantity and multiples

Tags: magento

In my magento store I have many producers that only accept orders in batches.

The most common is with chairs: the minimum amount is 4 unit and his multiples, for example 8, 12, 16 ecc. Quantity between those amounts will not be accepted.

So i already know how to setup a minum amount, but not how to setup amount in batches; in this way, when the user select the quantity, if quantity is not 4 or one of it's multiples the user will be noticed by an error.

Is there a way to acheive this with base installation without modify the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can manage this using magento default feature `Enable Qty Increments` in `Inventory` Tab on product edit page.

Please find the image below:

[image]